# Integration by parts. Which is the simplest way for this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Which is the easiest way to compute the following integral by parts?
$$\displaystyle\int\limits_{x}^{\infty}\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-s^2}ds$$?

Given that $\int f'(x)\cdot g(x)=f(x)\cdot g(x)-\int f'(x)\cdot g(x) +c$

could I choose $f(x)=e^{-s^2}$ and $g'(x)=1$?

Which is the simplest way to the solution of the integral by parts?

Comment: Neither way will work.  That function has no elementary primitive.

Comment: You won't be able to generate a solution for an arbitrary value of $x$ in terms of elementary functions.  This is the complementary error function.

Comment: @B.Goddard. Hey, what exactly is an elementary primitive?

Comment: A primitive is an anti-derivative.  There is no primitive of your integrand in term of algebraic, trig or exponential functions.  To get a primitive, you have to invent a new function (in this case, the new function is erfc(x).  )

Answer (score 2):

To nitpick a few comments, it is impossible to find the *antiderivative* of this function in terms of elementary functions. However, it is perfectly possible to compute this integral.

First, recall that the integral is a linear operator, which is a fancy term for saying that $\int af(x)dx = a \int f(x)dx$ and $\int (f(x)+g(x))dx =  \int f(x)dx+\int g(x)dx$.

So to start, we can express the integral as:

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_x^\infty e^{-s^2}ds$$

If you wanted to find the *antiderivative* of this function, you would need a series expansion, and to express the result in terms of a series. However, it is perfectly possible to find this specific integral with a little trick.

Let's set $I = \int_x^\infty e^{-s^2}ds$ (we'll multiply by the constant fraction in the end). Let's also restrict this answer to $x \geq 0$: it's easy to observe that $e^{-x^2}$ is even, so all we would need to do to find the answer for $x<0$ is compute $2*\int_0^\infty e^{-s^2}ds-\int_{|x|}^\infty e^{-s^2}ds$. Observe that $I = \int_x^\infty e^{-t^2}dt$ as well, so:

$$I^2 = \int_x^\infty e^{-s^2}ds*\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2}dt$$

$t$ and $s$ are constant realative to each other, so:

$$I^2 = \int_x^\infty \int_x^\infty e^{-s^2}e^{-t^2}dsdt = \int_x^\infty \int_x^\infty e^{-(s^2+t^2)}dsdt$$

Observe that, if we were to plot the region of integration with respect to s and t, we would find that we are integrating from the quarter circle with radius $x$ in quadrant I to the quarter circle with radius $c$ in quadrant I, where $c$ increases without bound.

So how does this help us? Well, we can integrate much more easily if we use polar coordinates, because while the differential in linear coordinates is $ds*dt$ (the area of a small rectangle in those coordinates), if we integrate with variables $r = \sqrt{s^2+t^2}$ and $\theta  = arctan(t/s)$, the differential is $r*dr*ds$. So:

$$I^2 = \int_x^\infty \int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-r^2}*r*d\theta dr = \frac{\pi}{2}\int_x^\infty e^{-r^2}*rdr = -\frac{\pi}{4}[e^{-r^2}]_x^\infty = \frac{\pi}{4} e^{-x^2}$$

So, for $x \geq 0$

$$I = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$$

Which means that for $x \geq 0$:

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_x^\infty e^{-s^2}ds = e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$$

And for $x < 0$:

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_x^\infty e^{-s^2}ds = 2*e^{-\frac{0^2}{2}}-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} = 2-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$$

Note that this does not contradict the idea that $e^{-x^2}$ does not have an elementary antiderivative. You cannot differentiate the result here to get back the original function. This can only be used to calculate actual numerical areas given that one of your upper bound is infinite.

Comment: By the way, if someone finds something wrong here, please nitpick it. I was surprised that I was able to figure out such a simple solution, and so I'm very open to the possibility that I screwed up. I double and triple checked this, so I do not THINK this incorrect, but it's very possible I made a mistake.

Comment: First nitpick:  This doesn't answer the question of "how to use integration by parts."  Second nitpick, you should be able to use Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and take the derivative of both sides of your second last equation and the results should be equal.

Comment: I know that it doesn't answer the integration by parts part of the question, because it is impossible to solve the integral by integration by parts. I proposed an alternate solution instead. As to the second, I am aware that this should be the case, and it's why I'm leery of saying my answer is correct, but I can't find the flaw in my answer either, especially since it's a standard technique I've seen before.

Comment: I think your problem is that your "quarter circles" are centered at the origin, so they are not the same as the region $[x,\infty] x [x,\infty],$

Comment: B Goddard is absolutely correct, though it took me a bit to think it through. I'm working on an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use integration by parts on this; the function doesn't have an antiderivative which can be expressed with elementary ("normal") functions.

You may find it interesting to note that at $x=0$, your integral evaluates to $1$; this is known as the [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).